# Repetitiveness and the reason for the way of reading the Torah on Hanukkah

Tags: chanuka, torah-reading

Why is it during Hanukkah that the reading of the Torah (according to the Ashkenazi Nusach Sfard) is repeated again on Shlishi? Was it not possible to add other verses? And why is the reading different on the first day and the last day (Zot Hanukkah)? And why is it in Zot-Hanukkah also adds days beyond the eighth (on the ninth day, etc.)?

Comment: This is not a uniform practice. Some do add verses